# Converting a floating point number to string with MPFR

Tags: c++, floating-point, mpfr

I want to convert a MPFR floating point number into a string.
If I run my program the string is generated but without the "." in the number. How can I do it right?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mpreal.h>

using mpfr::mpreal;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
    char data[255];
    mpreal x = 42.0, y = 3.14159265358979323846, res = 0.0;
    mp_exp_t exponent = 10;

    // string data_str[256];

    int precision = 50;
    res = x * y;

    cout.precision(100);
    cout << res;
    cout << "\n";

    // if (mpfr_snprintf (data, 254, "%.20Ff", res.mpfr_srcptr()) < 0)
/*
    if (mpfr_snprintf (data, 254, "%.20Ff", res.mpfr_srcptr()) < 0)
    {
        cout << "gmp_prints_float: error saving string!\n";
    }
    */

    mpfr_get_str ((char *) &data, &exponent, 10, precision, res.mpfr_srcptr(), GMP_RNDN);

    cout << data;
    cout << "\n";

     mpfr_free_cache ();
}
```

131.946891450771317977341823279857635498046875
13194689145077131797734182327985763549804687500000

There is no decimal point in the string output!

Comment: [Per the docs](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html) this is how it is supposed to behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

> The generated string is a fraction, with an **implicit** radix point immediately to the left of the first digit. For example, the number -3.1416 would be returned as "-31416" in the string and 1 written at expptr.

It is up to you to generate a human-readable representation fron the string and the exponent.

An alternative would be to use `mpfr_sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks to every one for the help!

Answer (score 0):

MPFR's `mpfr_get_str` function is copied on GMP's `mpf_get_str` function, explaining why it has been chosen not to write a decimal point. There are two solutions to have a decimal point:

1. Use `mpfr_sprintf` (or some variant), as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58102478/3782797). I would recommend this solution (perhaps unless you want to ignore the locales), as it is the most flexible in the output format and does not need a correction.
2. If you just want the significand with an explicit decimal point, use `mpfr_get_str`, but with a pointer `buffer+1` instead of `buffer`. Then, do something like (disregarding the locales)

```
    int neg = buffer[1] == '-';
    if (neg)
      buffer[0] = '-';
    buffer[neg] = '.';
```

after filtering the special cases (NaN and infinities).